# How can I use an if statement in bash to check if no errors have occurred?

Tags: bash, stderr

I have a bash script I want to self-destruct on execution.  So far it works great **but** I'd like some final check that if no errors have occurred (any output to stderr), then go ahead and self destruct.  Otherwise, I'd like to leave the script in tact.  I have the code for everything except the error check.  Not sure if I can just output err to a file and check if file is empty.  I'm sure it's a simple solution.

How could I do this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the command but looking it up it seems so.  Does it provide the stderr output as well?  I figured I can put set -e at the top of the script and if it gets to the rm -- "$0", then I'll assume it went great.

Comment: No, `set -e` has nothing to do with STDERR, it just deals with exit codes. Note though that just because a command prints to STDERR it doesn't mean that it has failed. A lot of commands just use it for logging. A command's exit code *should* indicate its success.

Comment: Oh, I get it now.  Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your script returns the value 0 on success, a value from 1 to 255 if an error occur you can use the following command

```
if /path/to/myscript; then
    echo success
else
    echo failed
fi
```

you can also use the following (shorter) command

```
[[ /path/to/myscript ]] &&  echo success || echo failed
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this out. $? contains the return code for the process last executed by command. Moreover standard nix derivatives demarcate 0 as (no error) and 1 - 255 as some kind of errors that happened. Note that this will report errors that do not necessarily have any stderr output.

```
command
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "command failed";
    # your termination logic here
    exit 1;
fi
```